# Is there a way to pause the loading screen?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

When you start Deus Ex Human revolution the loading screen is different and displays a summary of the plot. You can scroll with the arrows to change the part of the plot that is displayed and the picture.

My problem is that the loading is too quick and I can't read the whole text. And later, when I load the game before quitting it, the loading screen only shows some gameplay tips. So is there a method to pause the first loading or prevent the loading screen to close after the game has finished loading?

Comment: You don't often hear people complain about _short_ loading screens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading screen pauses automatically on the Xbox 360 version, but I confirmed that it does not pause on the PC version.  [This thread](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=121216) on the Eidos forum seems to confirm that it's an issue for more than just you and I, and there doesn't appear to be a fix.

One suggested solution is to screenshot the loading screens, assuming you have enough time to get through all of them before your rig completes the loading.  You can also use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> menu to review your objectives for the last few missions and other data entries you've collected to help your memory.

Alternatively, you could review a [plot synopsis](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex:_Human_Revolution) but you'd have to be careful not to read too far and get spoiled.